# Accessing other html files on a cloudfront distribution hosting a react app

Tags: reactjs, react-router, amazon-cloudfront, react-router-v4

I have a react app that's hosted on AWS Cloudfront, and the default root is set to index.html, which loads the react app.

So far so good.

I created a new html page `page1.html`, and then tried accessing it using the full URL, `https://my.site.com/page1.html`.

Uh oh.

The React app is loaded, and it's router intercepted the URL, and displayed the page not found error. React has no knowledge of the html page, which sounds about right.

If the cache is cleared the `page1.html` file loads correctly, however as soon as the react app is loaded, the react router starts intercepting the `page1.html` URL.

Why is that? I kind of expected the direct URL to load the html file bypassing the react app.

And is there a way to add an exception in react router to allow the page to be loaded without being intercepted?

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/61660051/10221416