# How to make a ReactJS app active/visible on AWS

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I developed a reactJS project (front-end) on AWS which has it RESTFUL API coming from heroku. They are completly separated i.e the frontend and backend.

I have successfully uploaded my files to S3, and have activated my CloudFront Distributions, but I can't really figure out what is wrong because I can't see my react app when I hit the URL generated from the Domain name.

I have checked this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41250087/how-to-deploy-a-react-nodejs-express-application-to-aws#41250688), but it doesn't help.

Please any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/50250307/5171417 . I have answered it in that post and it worked. Please check.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it is perfectly fine to deploy them on different servers/cloud. Can you give the URL ? I feel it is not issue of different clouds but configuration issue. Can you first put a simple html file on same S3 bucket and see if you can access that via your domain name.

Suppose you have your react app example.com hosted in bucket named ant. So, go ahead and put additional test.html in bucket ant. Then try example.com/test.html .. This will make sure your domain setting etc. are proper

Comment: that's exactly what I did, but I'm left with a white blank page.

Comment: is it a blank page ; or page not found ! Did you put some text in your test.html ? Could you see that text on browser ?

Comment: I mean I get a blank page because I don't render my react app from the `index.html` but I have `js` files in my views that renders all my views. Funny how the whole thing works fine on local, but AWS doesn't seem to get what I'm doing

Comment: can u give me your domain name you are trying.. let me debug it out.. it should not be that hard.

Comment: this index.html is coming up fine.. I did view source on this file.. Do not see anything there loading your RESTFul API.. All you are doing is including some jquery etc js ! Are you sure when you load this index.html on your local laptop it works fine !

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171505/discussion-between-antzshrek-and-deepak).

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced similar issues trying to run a react.js app through cloudront, here are a few things you should check:

- Make sure that your s3 hosting bucket has public read access, or that you have set up your cloudfront origin access policy with the s3 bucket by first creating an origin access identity in cloudfront, then associating the identity with your s3 bucket through the access policy:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "MyPolicy",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::cloudfront:user/CloudFront Origin Access Identity YOUR_CLOUDFRONT_ORIGIN_ACCESS_ID"
            },
            "Action": "s3:GetObject",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR_S3_BUCKET/*"
        }
    ]
}
```

- Make sure your s3 bucket has a cors policy allowing requests from any domain similar to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
<CORSRule>
    <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
    <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
    <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
    <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    <AllowedHeader>Content-Length</AllowedHeader>
</CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```

- If your package.json file in the react.js app has a homepage, you should remove it as this the application expects to be hosted from that url and not the cloudfront domain. Example package.json with homepage:

```
{
  "name": "your-package-name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "author": "",
  "homepage": "https://somepage.com/home",
  "repository": {},
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

- Make sure that your root object in the cloudfront distribution is index.html
- Make sure that after you run "npm run build" in the react app, you are only syncing your build folder with the s3 bucket.
- Make sure that if you use the aws cli to move your build files to the s3 bucket, you use the command "aws s3 sync build/ s3://YOUR_DEPLOY_BUCKET/ --acl public-read --delete", this ensures that only the most recent build files are uploaded to s3, and that any old files are deleted.
- After pushing files to s3, it is a good idea to run a cloudfront invalidation to ensure that your old files are removed from the cache and any new requests serve up the new files. you can run "aws cloudfront create-invalidation --distribution-id YOUR_CF_DISTRIBUTION_ID --paths '/*'" to accomplish this.
- Because react.js uses the virtual dom, and the only html document actually served is the index.html document, you need to add custom error responses to your cloudfront distribution as cloudfront will expect to serve up web pages like about.html or contact.html depending on the route in your react app. I recommend adding custom error responses for http codes 400-404 and mapping the response to status code 200 with a redirect to the "/" route. This ensures that if cloudfront cant find a file such as about.html, it will stay on the index.html file (where your react app is) and react router will virtually route to your /about route. see below for example configuration:

[image: Cloudfront custom response code mapping]

Answer (score 0):

have you tried making setting S3 bucket to “public”? 
you can either set a policy for the entire bucket or to to make certain objects available publicly. 
[here’s an AWS manual](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/read-access-objects-s3-bucket/)

chances are, your react app needs something like that